# Change File Extension Language?

Tags: aptana

I know in notepad ++ this can be done easy by just using the language menu item then selecting your language.

In Aptana Studio 3 say I am working with a .tpl file from Open Cart. The source is all "greyed" out as it doesn't know its PHP code. How can I tell Aptana Studio 3 its PHP code?

Is this even possible?

Ive been looking for hours and cannot find anything :/

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the problem for just this file, you can right click on it in the File Explorer or App Explorer and choose Open with... > PHP Editor (you may have to click Other to get to the PHP Editor option).

To make all .tpl files open in the PHP Editor, go to Window > Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations and add *.tpl file and choose the editor you want it to use.